# How can I write a MATLAB function named kellen that takes three input arguments named trs, ch1,ch2?

Tags: matlab, function

**Problem description:**

`trs`  takes a row or column vector of string, and two characters as `ch1` and `ch2`. If `ch1` is matched with any element in `trs` then that element of `trs` will be replaced by `ch2`. If `ch1` is not in the vector, `trs` will be returned as unchanged.

A simple example:

Input: `ww = kellen({‘YOYO’, ‘YOYO’},’Y’,’X’)`,
output: `ww = {‘XOXO’,’XOXO’}`

I assume `strrep` function could make this problem easier but I would like to know the very basic level how MATLAB can handle this problem without using `strrep` function. So I request you guys please correct my code without using `strrep`function.

I  am new to MATLAB. Indeed, I am new to programming too. I know I had to learn C first for basic but I did not that why is I am to struggle.

Here is my code but it seems do not work.

```
function ww = kellen(trs,ch1,ch2)


[r c] = size(trs);
if r == 1 && c > 1
   for i = 1:c
       ind = trs{i} == ch1;
       trs{1,i}(ind==1) = ch2;
       ww = trs;
   end
if r == 1 && c ==1
   for i = 1:c
       ind = trs{i} == ch1;
       trs{1,i}(ind==1) = ch2;
       ww = trs
   end
end
```

My code works fine when size of string vector is row vector but my function is not working fine when i pass scalar of trs string. For instance:

```
kellen({ 'peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers' }, 'p', 'b')
```

Which part of my code should i modify?

Comment: Please explain more what "seems to not work", does it error or just produce the wrong output? If the latter, then please explain exactly what was wrong with the output

Comment: >> ww = kellen({'YOYO', 'YOYO'},'Y','X')
Error using  == 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in kellen (line 7)
       if trs{i} == 'ch1'

Comment: Your output variable is `ww` and this is set to be a copy of `trs`. It isn't modified anywhere else, so unless it fails then it will return the input unmodified.

Comment: Thank you xenoclast for your hints

Comment: Your `if` statements are completely unnecessary. Why should you handle a scalar or row vector differently? There is no need. Also you are missing an `end`

Comment: Also you can just use `(ind)` rather than `(ind==1)`. They are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i = 1:c
    if trs{i} == 'c1'
       outp = [trs 'c2'];
    else
       return
    end
end
```

The first problem I see with your code is the line: `if trs{i} == 'c1'`

There are a lot of problems here:

1. By putting `'...'` quotes around `ch1` you are making `ch1` a string literal, NOT the variable for character one that was passed into your function. Drop the quotes. **This is the source of your error, attempting to equate a 4 character string with a 3 character string.**
2. You are equating a whole string `trs{i}` with a single character `ch1`. You can do that in Matlab, but NOT in an `if` statement. Let's take your example inputs, `trs{1}` is `'YOYO'` and if we try `'YOYO'=='Y'` we get a logical vector like [1 0 1 0]. Now `if` expects just a `1` or `0` and not a vector.

So I would suggest dropping the if statement and taking advantage of Matlab's logical indexing instead:

```
outp{c} = [];  %// this is just preallocation
for i = 1:c
    temp = trs{i};
    idx = temp==ch1 %// Get a logical matrix of which characters match
    temp(idx)=ch2; %// Use logical indexing to replace all the characters that match in this string in one go!
    outp{i} = temp;
end
```

Once you understand this code you can simplify:

```
outp = trs;
for i = 1:c
    outp{i}(outp{i}==ch1)=ch2
end
```

Comment: Thank you Dan. So i guess i should work based on logical vector [1 0 1 0]. Is not it?

Comment: Well Dan, i modified my code just a little bit and i think i am little closer to it but an important job is not done yet. And that is my code does not replace the element that is matched in string by ch2. Here is an input: ww = kellen({'YOYO', 'YOYO'},'Y','X') and i got output like that: ww = 

    'YOYO'    'YOYO'    . please help.

Comment: @novicecoder I have added a possible solution for you to explore.

Comment: Thank You Dan. Your code works perfectly and seemed you are at professional level. As i am a novice so i think i should make solution. I made a solution but having problem with this, i just edited my question based on my solution. My solution is not working for scalar type of trs but it works fine for row vector of trs. Please give me clue about bug. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ismember()` to find the locations where `ch1` is present in `trs`. So, in fact  `trs(ismember(trs,ch1)) = ch2;` will replace all instances of `ch1` with `ch2` in `trs`.

However, you need to make sure that `ch1` and `ch2` are exactly one characters long. If you want to have `trs` as a cell of strings, like in your question, than you can either loop through it the way you do now, or you can take a look at the `cellfun()` function.

Comment: if `ch1` etc is just a single character then you can use `==` instead of `ismember`...

Comment: Thank You Tamas for your hints.